# variable in nth-child() jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

i have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var max_count = $(".slider").children().length;
    function fn_get_natural_dim(slide_image,img){
        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;
        var ratiow = width/600;
        var ratioh = height/400;

        if(ratiow>=ratioh)
            {
            height = height/ratiow;
            $(slide_image).css("width","600px");
            $(slide_image).css("height",height);
            var margin = (400-height)/2;
            $(slide_image).css("margin-top",margin);
            }
        else
            {
            width = width/ratioh;
            $(slide_image).css("width",width);
            $(slide_image).css("height","400px");
            var margin = (600-width)/2;
            $(slide_image).css("margin-left",margin);
            }
    }
    for(var count=1;count<=max_count;count++)
        {
        var count_string = count.toString();
        var img_name = "img" + count_string;
        var slide_image = $('.slider > li:nth-child(" + count + ")');

        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = (function(slide_image,img){
            return function() {fn_get_natural_dim(slide_image,img);};
        })(slide_image,img);
        img.src = $(slide_image).attr("src");
        }
});
```

i want the variable slide_image to select the nth list, where n should be the same as the variable count.
i added the + signs (although i dont know why i have to) and made the quote symbols different, and yet it still doesnt work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
$('.slider > li:nth-child(' + count + ')');
```

The problem is that you're not closing the strings/segments surrounding the variable, so:

```
'.slider > li:nth-child(" + count + ")'
```

Is just a long string, a selector which makes no sense; that's why it matches nothing, you have to actually separate the sections by ending the static parts with the same kind of quote...